# How to search a data from multiple tables in C# using SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

Example: If I have `ID` column in 4 tables (candidate, exam, interview, final_list) and I want to know my status (i.e if I am enter id = 10) it displays only "you are in exam list". Even if id 10 also exists in other tables (e.g. interview and final_list). As soon as it gets to the first table containing id, display some message and end. 10q 
  here is my code

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        SqlCommand command;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        int i = 0;
        string fsql = null;
        string ssql = null;
        string tsql = null;
        string fosql = null;

        fsql = "select * from final_list where ID='" + txtcandidateno.Text + "'";
        ssql = "select * from interview where ID='" + txtcandidateno.Text + "'";
        tsql = "select * from interview where ID='" + txtcandidateno.Text + "'";
        fosql = "select * from interview where ID='" + txtcandidateno.Text + "'";
        try
        {
            sql.Open();

            command = new SqlCommand(fsql, sql);
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            adapter.Fill(ds, "final_list");

            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = ssql;
            adapter.Fill(ds, "interview");

            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText =tsql;
            adapter.Fill(ds, "exam");
            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = fosql;
            adapter.Fill(ds, "candidate");

            adapter.Dispose();
            command.Dispose();
            sql.Close();

            //retrieve first table data 
            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {


                    MessageBox.Show("you are final list");




            }


            //retrieve second table data 
            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {



                    MessageBox.Show("you are interview list");



            }

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[2].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("you are exam list");

            }

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[3].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("you are normal cadidate list");

            }








        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }

        }
```

in the above code what it happen it search from final_list to candidate sequentially but if the id is found in first loop it also search other but if the id is not found in first but exist in other table e.g candidate table it does not display. what i want is if the id e.g in second table only display "you are in interview list " and end. search from final_list to candidate until the first table exists that contains the id.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried, and reword this to be more readable.

Comment: You are over complicating it. Consider using an entity data model as opposed to a dataset. Make each model derive from a base model. This way you can keep a list of all the results in the same collection.  Then you can use Linq or Lambda on the collection similarly to what @sukotto suggested.

Answer (score 1):

At this point it is impossible to guess what you've tried, or if you are looking for an answer in SQL or C# (as there are no code examples), but it seems that you need to check the tables incrementally? In pseudocode:

```
if (id is in candidate)
   You are in "candidate"
else if (id is in exam)
   You are in "exam"
```

If you are using Linq to SQL that might look like

```
if (db.Candidate.Any(x => x.Id == id)) {...}
else if (db.Exam.Any(x => x.Id == id)) {...}
```